# Google Analytics - URL working in web browser, not in Unity Editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, unity-editor

I made a fresh app, follow [the instruction for Unity](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/devguide), add button to send Hit, and the console log (200) success on every of my hit. If I copy past the logged ULR into a web browser (chrome/Firefox) I did receive the event on Analytics real time reports. However, I don't receive ANY hits from the application (Unity editor or Android devices).

Do you have any advice ? Look's like some weird firewall issues, but it would work on Android that way....

Thanks for your readings,

News1 -
Ok, it did works for Android now ! Apparently in my test I mismatch the UA between other tracking code and Android tracking code.
However, still not working in Editor. And firewall is off

News2 -
It works on Android, but not with Windows build while I am on the same network (internet hotspot or same wifi)

Comment: Are you sure it applied the permissions for accessing the internet?

Comment: Yes I did following this instruction  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/devguide (Choose a platform for configuration details:) (I don't use campaign tracking)

Comment: It look like it doesn't works on Windows